# Trouble using String.Format() with a DateTime array

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime, string-formatting

I would appreciate help in understanding why the following C# code does not work.

```
//string[] array = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" }; // this array works
var array = new [] {
       new DateTime(2000, 1, 1),
       new DateTime(2010, 12, 31)
};

var format = "{0:MMM}{1:MMM}";

Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format, array)); // compiles, but crashes at runtime
```

It compiles without issue, but crashes with the following error upon execution:

> **Run-time exception (line 15): Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.**
>
> Stack Trace: [System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.]
>      at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
>      at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
>      at System.String.Format(String format, Object arg0)
>      at Program.Main() :line 15

I expected that [the String.Format overload that accepts an object array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object___) would work with the DateTime array just as it works with the string array, but am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: This won't work because it will consider the array to be item 0, and there won't be an item 1, hence the exception. You need to change the code to pass the items individually: `string.Format(format, date1, date2)`

Comment: Just a small point, you don't need to call `string.Format` inside `Console.WriteLine`, just use `Console.WriteLine(format, array);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `DateTime[]` is not an `object[]`; that isn't how array variance works - so: if you pass a `DateTime[]` array to `string.Format`, it isn't using the `Format(string, object[])` overload - you're *effectively* using passing the entire `DateTime[]` as a *single* object to `Format(string, object)`, hence from `Format`'s perspective, you can only use token `0`.

Basically, use:

```cs
var array = new object[] {
       new DateTime(2000, 1, 1),
       new DateTime(2010, 12, 31)
};
```

and it should work.

Comment: I'm sorry it's tardy, but thank you very much, Marc. This was just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

`var format = "{0:MMM}{1:MMM}";` expects three arguments supplied for `string.Format()` - one for format and two arguments for values.

Like

```
string.Format(format, array[0], array[1])
```

another option is to change array from `DateTime[]` to `object[]` array